# A value is not bound correctly in a vector

Tags: c++

I have a problem in an optimisation step that can be summarised essentially as

```
auto s = v.size();
```

Where `v` is a `std::vector<double`. (Essentially this is a vector characterizing a symmetric function).

I then have an index `i` which needs to be between `-s` and `+s`. So I use the following code:

```
if (i < -s || i > s)
```

But this passes for low values of `i`. Can anyone shed any light on why this does not work? If it is relevant, `i` is of type `int`.

Comment: How can an index be negative?

Comment: That relates to the symmetric nature of the function. Trust me ;-)

Comment: What's the type of `i`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen, 'If it is relevant, i is an int type.'

Comment: Use an absolute value of `i`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen a more apt question would be what is the type of *s*.

Comment: If the vector is "characterizing a symmetric function" you can store only the values related to positive "indeces" and then retrive only those ones: `if ( i < 0 ) i = -i;` then test for `if ( i < s ) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the question and some of your comments, it appears you are thinking that `auto` does something a little different.

Since C++11, it's no longer used to denote *simply* a variable of *automatic* storage duration (as opposed to `static` for example), but also infers the *type* from the thing it's being assigned to. (But note that `auto s` in pre-C++11 days is a syntax error: you'd need to explicitly supply the type).

So the *type* of `s` is actually `std::vector<double>::size_type` which is an `unsigned` type. This is where the fun starts.

The operation of the unary minus operator on an unsigned type is itself unsigned. (Actually such that `-s + s` *just* wraps round to zero). Furthermore, *type promotion* of `int` to `unsigned` means that *expressions* like `i < -s` are evaluated in *unsigned arithmetic*.

It is these effects that is causing the confusion.

If I were you, I'd convert the negative values of `i` using `std::abs`.

There's quite a few technical terms in this answer; I've italicised the ones that you should research further.

Comment: Thanks bathsheba. this is clear. and I like some of your other answers

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is `-s` does not give you the opposite value of the size.  `s` is going to be some unsigned integer type (most likely `std::size_t`).  Since it is unsigned it cannot be negative, so `-s` will underflown and become `maximum_value_s_can_hold - s`.

If you want to check if some value is not inside the range of `(-size, size)` then you will need to store the size in a signed integer variable. If you know what the likely range of values is then you can use a data type that will hold those values.  Otherwise I would suggest you use a `long long` or [`std::ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t).

Comment: @Puglia No problem.  It gets a lot of people.

Comment: By the way my colleague said I should write auto int.

Comment: @Puglia `auto int` is syntactically incorrect.  I suggest `std::ptrdiff_t` or `long long` for the data type of `s`.

Comment: @Puglia I suggest using `int` if you could reasonably count it by hand and `std::int64_t` otherwise. But if `i` is `int`, then `s` can just be `int` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to understand what is going on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> a{1};
    auto s = a.size();
    cout << -s;
    return 0;
}
```

What do you see as the result? Not -1, right?

So, I believe you meant to use as follows:

```
auto s = static_cast<int>(v.size());
```

Now, if you write `if (i < -s || i > s)` you get expected result.

Comment: Perhaps I should stick to fortran 90!

Comment: @Puglia If you want to see the same behavior in fortan 90, then use int as in `auto s = static_cast<int>(v.size())`

Comment: I would not cast the size to an `int`.  It makes the code brittle.

Comment: @NathanOliver I wouldn't even write `if (i < -s || i > s)` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In the following

```
std::vector<T> v;
auto s = v.size();
```

`s` is declared as `auto`, that means, to be deduced by it's RHS. `vector::size()` returns `vector::size_type`, which is

> Unsigned integral type (usually `std::size_t`)

Now `-s` produces an (quiet) underflow ; big number almost certainly greater then any index of the vector.

To check whether the number is between `(-s, s)`, you have to convert `s` to signed type (preferably `long long int`, since it's at least 64-bits, or any of [Fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) if required).